# Erro in Alert method

Tags: javascript, dynamic

I have this code below, but when the user remove all list nodes, I mean, all `<li>`, an `alert` message should appear, when button Limpar Lista are pressed and there are no more nodes to remove, but this is the error that appears:

`Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'removeChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'. at HTMLInputElement.removeElement (script.js:26)`

```
const $list = document.querySelector('ul')
const $product = document.querySelector('#product')
const $btn = document.querySelector('#btn')
const $reset = document.querySelector('#reset')
 
$btn.addEventListener('click', addProduct)
 
function addProduct() {
    const $item = `<li>${$product.value}</li>`
    $list.innerHTML += $item
    $product.value = ''
    $product.focus()
}
 
$product.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => {
    if (e.keyCode === 13) {
        addProduct()
    }
})
 
$reset.addEventListener('click', removeElement)
 
function removeElement() {
    // Removes an element from the document
    const $ul = document.getElementById("list");
    $ul.removeChild($ul.children[0])
    if($product = '') {
        alert('A lista está vazia')
    }
}
```

Comment: have you tried `$ul.childNodes[0]` instead of `children`?

Comment: If all elements are removed `$ul.children` will be empty and `$ul.children[0]` will return `undefined`. That is why "_parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'_". But what is your goal with `if($product = '')`? First `=` is for assignment, not for comparison and `$product` is a DOM element, not a string.

Comment: $product = ' ' is the same as $product.length == 0

Answer (score 0):

When the list is empty, this statement will return undefined:

```html
$ul.children[0]
```

Add a test for that so that you only remove an element if there is one. Otherwise show the alert when there is no first element.

```html
if ($ul.children[0] != undefined) {
  $ul.removeChild($ul.children[0]);
}
else {
  alert("...");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, your problem is when pressing the delete button with no `<li>` tags being left. If so, the issue is you're selecting the first element of an array that doesn't exist or is empty. Checking for the array should fix it:

```
if($ul.children[0]) {
    $ul.removeChild($ul.children[0])
}
```